# Unable to find a match for 'manpôwer.com' although domain information is available

Tags: ruby, whois, whois-ruby

I am encountering an issue while using the whois gem, as it fails to locate any records for the domain name 'manpôwer.com'.

```
No match for "MANPôWER.COM".
>>> Last update of whois database: 2023-03-22T14:56:58Z <<<
```

My understanding is that the gem relies on the Verisign database for domain information, and this domain can be located through either the Verisign database or other third-party websites. I am using the latest version of the gem and am unsure what may be the issue. Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'whois'
=> true

irb(main):003:0> Gem.loaded_specs["whois"].version
=> #<Gem::Version "5.1.0">

irb(main):004:0> Whois.whois("manpôwer.com")
=> "No match for \"MANP\xC3\xB4WER.COM\".\r\n>>> Last update of whois database: 2023-03-22T15:25:36Z <<<\r\n\r\nNOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the\r\nregistrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is\r\ncurrently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration\r\ndate of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring\r\nregistrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to\r\nview the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.\r\n\r\nTERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois\r\ndatabase through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and\r\nautomated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or\r\nmodify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry\r\nServices' (\"VeriSign\") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for\r\ninformation purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information\r\nabout or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not\r\nguarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide\r\nby the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only\r\nfor lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data\r\nto: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass\r\nunsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone,\r\nor facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes\r\nthat apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,\r\nrepackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly\r\nprohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to\r\nuse electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or\r\nquery the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register\r\ndomain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right\r\nto restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure\r\noperational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the\r\nWhois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign\r\nreserves the right to modify these terms at any time.\r\n\r\nThe Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and\r\nRegistrars.\r\n"
```

Comment: It's possible that the library/API doesn't do the necessary IDN encoding automatically. Does querying `xn--manpwer-w0a.com` instead work?

Comment: I tried before as you suggested and it worked, however, I wasn't aware that I had to do IDN encoding before sending the request. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names in queries should always be specified as Punycode. Unicode it's used only for display, never in network calls (or in this case whois queries).

The following statement should produce the expected result:

```
Whois.whois("xn--manpwer-w0a.com")
```

To convert the name, you can use one of the various online tools like https://www.punycoder.com/. Alternatively, if you want to script the conversion in Ruby, use the [simpleidn gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/simpleidn).